# Question about the meaning of $0\rightarrow B$ used in category theory and elsewhere in mathematics

Tags: category-theory, notation, morphism

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors: The Categorical Imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

**Definition:**  Let $\textbf{K}$ be a category with zero object $0$.  Then the **kernel** $u: K \to A$ of $f: A \to B$ is given by the pullback diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K @>>> 0 \\
@V{\large u\,}VV @VVV \\
A @>>{\large f}> B
\end{CD}$$

What I would like to know is what does the map $0 \to B$ in the pullback diagram above mean? Is it like the zero map $f: X \to Y$ is defined as $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$ or does it mean that it is a zero morphism (not sure if there is such a term).

I have seen it also defined this way in the context of exact sequence.  Also, I often just see it as $0 \to B$ without any letter assign to it denoting the name of the map.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about the properties of zero objects.

Comment: An object is called a "zero object" if it's both initial and terminal, meaning for every objects $A$ and $B$ there exist unique arrows $A \to 0$ and $0 \to B$. What these arrows are depends entirely on what category you're in (and not all even have zero objects), but an example would be groups with group homomorphisms where $A \to 0$ is the zero map (send everything to zero) and $0 \to B$ is the map $0 \mapsto 0$ (the constant map sending zero to zero, as required by homomorphism). The composition $A \to 0 \to B$ is then unique, so kernels are unique if they exist.

Comment: That you see such maps in exact sequences is not a surprise considering exact sequences live over Abelian categories, which are categories with zero objects (and kernels) by hypothesis.

Comment: @DanRust lets say that we call the map $0\rightarrow B,$ $w$, and we have the maps $g:B\rightarrow M$ and $p:N\rightarrow 0$, then what do $g\circ w$ and $w\circ p$ equal to?  When i saw this notation in the context of the concept for exact sequence, there was no discussion about initial or final objects.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen as I replied to Dan Rust, what about the case $0\rightarrow B\rightarrow M$, what would that mean.  I am guessing you are saying what the notation means depends on the context of the category that one is speaking of?

Comment: @Seth In a general category with a $0$ you'll just get the unique maps $0 \to M$ and $N \to 0 \to B$ as your arrows. In the context of Abelian categories you can often consider Rmod instead (by, say, Freyd-Mitchell)  in which case $g \circ w = 0 \to M$ is the zero map (sends zero to zero) and $w \circ p = N \to 0 \to B$ is the map sending all elements of $N$ to the zero element of $B$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen for the case of general category, would $g\circ w$ be still consider the zero map?  Sorry I corrected my previous comment.  I am still new to category theory.  It seems like everytime I learn something new, I have to be careful which category/context for whatever I am learning will work.  I don't know why Abelian categories are so special versus general categories at this point.

Comment: @Seth It depends on what you mean by "zero map". Assuming your category has a zero object, then $0 \to M$ definitely exists and is unique, but the whole point is to be more abstract. Assuming the objects in the category are sets and that $0$ is a singleton then we can say $0 \to M$ is a constant map, but without knowing the structure of the category we can't really say much more, since there isn't necessarily any object called "zero" in $M$ to make it a zero map (and even if there is we need some algebraic structure to make sure $0$ gets mapped to $0$).

Comment: You shouldn't strictly think of arrows as functions on sets or algebraic structures, but should instead just think of $0$ as some object that has unique arrows in and out. The whole point of category theory is to reduce an argument about morphisms and objects to the bare essentials, by forgetting as much of the individual structure of the objects as possible while allowing the argument to still go through.

Comment: That said, perhaps an example would help. Suppose we are working over the category of groups. Then $K \to 0 \to B$ is the map sending $k \in K$ to $0_B$. Commutativity of the diagram means $f(u(k)) = 0_B$, i.e. $\text{im } u \subseteq \ker f$. The diagram above thus says, over groups, that a kernel of $f$ is a group homomorphism whose image is a subset of the things $f$ sends to zero.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen when you say "point of category theory is to reduce an argument about morphisms and objects to the bare essentials, by forgetting as much of the individual structure of the objects as possible", you mean as treating arrows as simply morphisms and don't assume any properties about them like one to one, onto, etc, or how in the case of a function $f$ that sends $0\righarrow B$, then $f(0)\in B$ and that is all that can be said, assuming $0$ is a singleton set.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Seth Some of that is accurate, but to emphasize what I said, you forget about the "individual structure of the **objects**". You still try to remember as much as possible about the morphisms, just in ways and language that is as object independent as possible. For example, we still care about injectivity and surjectivity, but we can't define them in the standard way (since injectivity talks about elements of objects being equal, and surjectivity talks about every element of an object being reached, and we want to avoid mentioning elements of objects)...

Comment: ... However, we *do* have [monomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism) and [epimorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism), which are their categorical analogue and only talk about properties describable in the general language of categories. Note the problem with injectivity and surjectivity is talk about what is *inside* of objects, e.g. consider the idea of a map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, where both talk about elements of $\mathbb R$. The key is to only talk about $\mathbb R$ itself, not the stuff inside of it.